# data-contenturl attribute in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Working on one project and find this interesting attribute **[data-contenturl]**  and did not find any information about it. 
The main sense of this code is that the action of the controller returns a partial view. This link is part of the tabs widget and should insert content from a partial view to the **#tab-body-id** element. This partial view contains jquery widget with initializing spec and data-bind. The main issue is that on first load everything works great but on the second and subsequent old jquery objects try to send request to data-bind request but the element is one that`s why causes errors in console. I tried to destroy these elements, unbind them, insert empty content to **#tab-body-id** before the second tab load but nothing helps.

Could someone please explain how this attribute works? I could forget about something. I`ll be glad for any ideas!

```html
<a href="#tab-body-id" data-toggle="tab" data-contenturl="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", 
new{ argument })">
```

And one more moment as additional information. 
When i remove this attribute from  and insert code

```html
<div id="tab-body-id">
 @{ Html.RenderPartial("route to my partial", Model.Id); }
</div>
```

directly to my **#tab-body-id** all works fine, becouse it is only one request during initialization of view...

Comment: did you know about data Attribute. please read https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp

Comment: @Aishwarya Thank you, it directed me on the right track.

Comment: It's My Pleasure